# Unexpected end of line seen: Makefile

Tags: makefile, solaris, gnu-make

Have a setup.mk file with the following:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -g -O2 -c -Wall -pthreads

VER = 64

ifneq (32, $(VER))
<tab>CC += -m64    # Line 26
endif

PROCESSOR = big

ifeq (little, $(PROCESSOR))
<tab>CFLAGS += -DLITTLE_ENDIAN
endif
```

When I make through command line, this works fine.  When I make through my deployment tool (Vulcan), however, I get the following error:

"make: Fatal error in reader: /[path]/setup.mk, line 26: Unexpected end of line seen"

Note the following:

```
>echo $PATH
>/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

>which make
>/usr/gnu/bin/make
```

Logged in as same user when deploying through Vulcan (using sshexec to run start_make.sh script).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Is that the whole `setup.mk` file? That doesn't have 26 lines in it. That also doesn't sound like a GNU make error to me.

Comment: @EtanReisner no, that is not the whole file.  I stripped out the comments and a bunch of path declarations and the like.  Is there a possibility that the "which make" I run via command line is not the same one used by the same login through the deployment tool?

Comment: What line in that snippet is line 26 of the original file? That is certainly possible.

Comment: "fatal error in reader" is something that Solaris make can output, so it looks like Vulcan might be ignoring your PATH.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happened @MarkPlotnick.  I added some debug in the build file to output PATH during vulcan deployment and it did not have /usr/gnu/bin at the front (or at all).  Thanks folks!